# Why coalesce does not result in a new stage?

Tags: apache-spark

When use coalesce to reduce the partition, there must be some data movement among executors right? Then this is so called "shuffle" according to my understanding.

If this is "shuffle", how come it does not result in a new stage?

I see some articles say coalesce does not avoid "shuffle", but it avoids "full shuffle", then what exactly the "full shuffle" is?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case of coalesce it combines existing partitions to reduce their number which means some previously existing partitions will stay on the same executors and other will be shuffled and combined with them (so only partial shuffling will occur). Full shuffle happens in case of repartition when you want to crate a different number of partitions so everything need to be created from scratch and shuffled.

Additionally during coalesce algorithm partition locality is considered so 2 partition being on the same executor may be compacted without shuffling but it's not always the case so that's why "partial shuffling".

Also coalesce doesn't result in a new stage by design. It's kind of metadata operation describing how the partitions from earlier processing steps should be combined but the work is done by those earlier stages (which in some cases is unintentional).